How do I get the payment method in an order export profile?
I created an individual export profile for orders via the Import/Export-Modile in Shopware 6.
I would like to add "transactions.paymentMethod...." to a field to have the payment method with an export, but the field is always empty. By default there is also no auto-suggest for "transactions" – only for "deliveries". It seems like the association for transactions are missing, but how could i get this solved (adding the missing association)?
(same problem for the country of the shippingOrderAddress – i can get the translated name for the billing address country, but not for the shipping address country)
I already tried adding $criteria->addAssociation('transactions.paymentMethod') in vendor/shopware/core/Content/ImportExport/Event/Subscriber/CategoryCriteriaSubscriber.php  (just for testing reasons; also did a cache clear), but it didn't work out.
